# What would be the best method to position divs over each other using grid?

Tags: html, css

I made an etch-a-sketch board as a project and would like to place it in the middle of a nintendo switch like container. I was able to make the background and controllers as well as placing them where I wanted using grid-template-areas but ran into a block when trying to place another div that would be a black circle(for the analog stick) near the top of the left controller. What would be the best method to place everything? I will be making more a few more divs that will look like buttons on each controller as well.

```css
#gridContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
        'left-controller . grid-screen . right-controller'
        'left-controller . grid-screen . right-controller'
        'left-controller . grid-screen . right-controller';

    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#gridContainer {
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: black;
    width: 850px;
    padding-top: .8em;
    padding-bottom: .8em;
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.leftController {
    grid-area: left-controller;
    z-index: 1;

    background-color: crimson;
    width: 150px;
    height: 500px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;

}

.lc-analog {
    z-index: 2;

    background-color: black;
    height: 50px;
}

.rightController {
    grid-area: right-controller;
    z-index: 2;

    background-color: cyan;
    width: 150px;
    height: 500px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-area: grid-screen;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(16, 2fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 2fr);
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="gridContainer">
    <div class="leftController"></div>
    <div class="lc-analog"></div>
    <div class="rightController"></div>
    <div id="grid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want overlapping elements use `position: absolute`?

Comment: CSS Grid is not the tool for that job